# How do I get the value of a variable in a socket from the outside?

Tags: node.js

Need to get player name from browser client.

```
var playerName;    
socket.on('responsePlayer', (player) => { 
    playerName = player;
    });
console.log(playerName);
// undefined
```

Why is playerName not defined? How to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

move the last line in to socket.on:

```
var playerName;    
socket.on('responsePlayer', (player) => { 
    playerName = player;
    console.log("Player Name: " + playerName);
});
```

Comment: I need to use the value of a variable outside of the socket block.

Comment: set value for playerName first, example: var playerName = 'example';

Comment: i don't understan your idea. But, playerName = player; will run when socket get a message on 'responsePlayer'

Comment: playerName gets the value via a socket. Then I need to take this value and use it in other parts of the code. If this code is inside a socket block, it works. If the code that uses the value of the playerName variable is outside the socket block, the value of the playerName variable becomes undefined. Question: how do I pass the value of a variable received via a socket to external code? Is this possible in principle or not? If possible, I will look for a solution. If not, then the question is closed.